# Is it a good idea to perform data migration with generic language?

Tags: data-migration

There are two kinds of migration. One is to update database schema during the development period. The other is to migrate existing data into a new system (with different schema).

There are a lot of tools available for the former scenario, such as Flyway, Liqubase. However, I am not aware of tools for the latter purpose.

We are currently using `PL/SQL` to do the migration. However, not all our Java developers have a DBA background. I wonder if anyone has an experience of using generic languages (Java, Scala, C#, etc.) with database access libraries (Hibernate, NHibernate, etc.) to perform the migration.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what the question is, but if I understand you correctly;
Sure you can develop an application in a(ny) language that reads data from a data source and puts it into a data target.

A data migration between data sources does not have to be SQL to SQL only (in case source and target are relational databases)

In fact it often makes sense to have an application between the source/target if there's logic which needs to handle or transform data between various structures or between various data sources. 
For example if migrating data from one ERP system into an e-commerce system (just an example).

Another advantage to doing it via an application, is that you often can include more tools/features for reporting and error handling.
Especially if the integration/migration should run often, such error handling/reporting to verify the data movement is beneficial.

Also if the data source and data target are located in different areas/on different servers, it can be easier to do the migration via an application, to avoid opening up needlessly between servers and linking them together.

So basically - such an application (Java, C# ... anything) would read data from a data source, transform the data into the data structure of the target and then store it in the data target.

Making an application to do things, is just another tool in a developers toolbox.

However, if the data migration is basically a 1:1 movement of data from one structure to another duplicate of that structure and no transformation exists; then the situation would be faster/easier to handle directly in SQL or using a data-sync program.
Even if not "DBA background" (not many developers have DBA background, but that shouldn't prevent people from learning SQL, as it's also just another language. You don't need to be a DBA to be able to write SQL effectively)

So - in conclusion. Yes, you can write an application and yes, it can be a good idea. But as almost everything within our field, then it's a case-by-case/situation-by-situation evaluation whether or not it is the "better" way.

Comment: Thanks @Allan, you understood my question correctly (English is not my mother language). I understand the theories, but I am looking for real experience doing it.

Comment: Real experience is just doing it. There's no magic in it. Make an application, read data from source, handle data, save data to target.